# Subversion Command For Checking the list of files change given a timestamp

Tags: svn

We just transferred to Subversion from an old version control system and I am just trying to learn it on my windows machine using command line interface first.  (I know there is TortoiseSVN but there is more that I'd like to accomplish later... :) )

I just wanted to know if there is an SVN command that I could execute that will list to me all the files that was changed/added/deleted given a particular timestamp?

Example, I would monitor one of the folder in my subversion repository and given a particular date I would like to list all the files that were change/altered/deleted/added/updated in that particular repository.

Say, starting yesterday...I would like to list all those files.

is this possible?

Comment: Though someone have given the answer, I strongly suggest you have a read on SVN's official book at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ .  It has even mentioned on how to do exactly what you are asking now.  Have a brief scan on this book and know the basics first, instead of trying out blindingly

Comment: Thanks Adrian! I started with TortoiseSVN and its graphical user interface...after learning thru with TortoiseSVN and its Subversion basic, I just found a need to understand further about the command line interface.  I am still a newbie in this and just started learning today.  Thanks a lot for your link.  I was just hoping for a little consideration. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is:
you use the **svn log** command with -r switch:

```
svn log <URL_TO_YOUR_REPO> -r{YYYY-MM-DD}
```

From SVNs help:

```
   -r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                              A revision argument can be one of:
                                  NUMBER       revision number
                                 '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
                                 'HEAD'       latest in repository
                                 'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
                                 'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
                                 'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED
```

Keep in mind it shows you *all* revisions *before* that specific date. So to see everything from today (2012-10-15) you should write:

```
svn log <URL_TO_YOUR_REPO> -r{2012-10-16}:{2012-10-14}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly it's

```
svn diff -r{date}:{date}
```

More info [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html)